# Are these properties sufficient to characterize the cross product in three dimensions?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product

Given that $\times$ is an operation that takes two three-dimensional vectors $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ and outputs one three-dimensional vector $\boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b}$, are these properties sufficient to prove that it *is* the cross product?

**1. Magnitude**

$\left \| \boldsymbol{a}\times \boldsymbol{b} \right \|=\left \| \boldsymbol{a} \right \|\left \| \boldsymbol{b} \right \|\sin (\widehat{\boldsymbol{a};\boldsymbol{b}})$

**2. Right hand rule**

$\mathbf{\hat{i}} \times\mathbf{\hat{j}}=\mathbf{\hat{k}}$

**3. Continuity**

$\lim_{\Delta \boldsymbol{a}\rightarrow \mathbf{0}}(\boldsymbol{a}+\Delta \boldsymbol{a}) \times \boldsymbol{b} = \boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b}$

$\lim_{\Delta \boldsymbol{b}\rightarrow \mathbf{0}} \boldsymbol{a} \times (\boldsymbol{b}+\Delta \boldsymbol{b}) = \boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b}$

Comment: I don't think so: $a\times b= \|a\| \|b\| \sin\angle(a,b) \cdot k$ seems to fit your definition.

Answer (score 6):

No, all of these axioms are satisfied by the function $\| a \| \| b \| (\sin \theta) \hat{\bf{k}}$. It's a bad idea to try to characterize the cross product without including *bilinearity*!

The following axioms, on the other hand, *do* uniquely characterize the cross product:

1. Bilinearity: $(ax + by) \times z = a x \times z + b y \times z$ and the same in the second variable.
2. Antisymmetry: $x \times y = - y \times x$.
3. $x \times y$ is orthogonal to the plane spanned by $x$ and $y$, or equivalently $x \cdot (x \times y) = 0$ (which implies the same for $y$ by antisymmetry).
4. Right hand rule: $\hat{\bf{i}} \times \hat{\bf{j}} = \hat{\bf{k}}$.

Note that continuity follows automatically from bilinearity. This is a nice exercise; the idea is that the first three axioms imply that the triple product $x \cdot (y \times z)$ is trilinear and alternating (meaning it is equal to zero if any two of its inputs are equal) which means it must be a scalar multiple of the determinant of the matrix with columns $x, y, z$, and the fourth axiom fixes which multiple it is.

Alternatively, the following axioms also uniquely characterize the cross product:

1. Bilinearity again.
2. Rotation equivariance: if $R \in SO(3)$ is a rotation, then $(Rx) \times (Ry) = Rz$.
3. Right hand rule again.

This is because rotation equivariance together with the right hand rule determines the cross product of any two basis vectors and then we're done by bilinearity.

In the background here are some abstract facts about the [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) of the Lie group $SO(3)$ and its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ although none of that is strictly speaking necessary, it just helps organize what's going on.

Comment: The definition on Wikipedia in terms of normal vectors is awful. It's a mystery from that point of view why the cross product ends up being bilinear.

Comment: Is there any way we can do away with bilinearity?

Comment: @symmetrickittens: do you have any particular application in mind where this would be useful? What properties do you like if you don't like bilinearity? You can use the definition given on Wikipedia but as I've said I don't like it. It is equivalent to saying the following which I like a bit better: $x \times y$ is orthogonal to the plane spanned by $x$ and $y$, and $x \cdot (y \times z)$ is the signed volume of the parallelepiped determined by $x, y, z$ (the definition of "signed volume" includes a choice of orientation encoding the right hand rule).

Comment: This secretly encodes bilinearity, though, since the signed volume is trilinear. Anyway, as you can see there are lots of different things you can do here so it would help if you were more specific about your motivation here and what you're trying to understand.

Comment: Bilinearity just seems too strong a property to just have from the get-go.

Comment: Why? The dot product is bilinear. Lots of nice things are bilinear.

Comment: I was thinking about how to define the determinant in terms of the (generalized) cross product that makes it pops out that the 3-dimensional determinant is related to to the 2-dimensional one. I have already proven that the area of a parallelogram in three dimensions is the quadratic mean of the area of its projections to the Oxy, Oxz and Oyz planes aka the quadratic mean of the components of the cross product. Was looking to exploit this property as much as possible in the definition of the cross product itself. That means excluding some of the stronger axioms and see if it will work.